# Text as list item in multilevel CSS navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, standards

I need to add text before a horizontal navigation menu at the first, second and third levels of links.

The levels are achieved using nested lists.

If I want place text before a level of links, is it considered bad practice to add the said text as a list item?

## Example:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Some arbitrary text:</li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it goes against best practice, I would suggest doing

```
<span>Some Text:</span><ul>..</ul>
```

This keeps your html clean and more flexible.

Comment: That's a fresh solution, thanks. The only alternative I had in mind was to nest the list items for links within the list item for the text, which seemed overkill considering I'd be introducing a fourth level.